# Powershell script runs, but outputs an error: "The term ''$varArgs'' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable "

Tags: powershell, script

Apologies if this is a really simple thing, but I really struggle at understanding coding so I'm hoping someone can help me. I have the relatively simple Powershell script. It seems to run, but for the output I get this Stderr log message. If someone could let me know how to correct it I would appreciate it.

```
'$varArgs' : The term ''$varArgs'' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\ProgramData\CentraStage\Packages\2bc7843b-1d71-4c43-bb6a-1ececfde5a61#\command.ps1:25 char:18
+         $varArgs=`'$varArgs`'
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ('$varArgs':String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is the script:

```
# If you are reading this, you have copied the Component successfully,
# probably for the purposes of attaching your own configuration file.
# Near the bottom of this page, attach your .bgi file to the Component
# and then save the Component with a new name. The script will identify
# the presence of the file and alter the startup routines to use it.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# BGInfo installer/implanter :: build 17/seagull december 2020 :: thanks to michael mccool

write-host "Install and configure BGInfo to run on Startup"
write-host "============================================="

# install the executable somewhere we can bank on its presence
new-item -Path "$env:temp\BGInfo" -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
Move-Item bginfo4.exe "$env:temp\BGInfo" -Force
Move-Item bginfo8.exe "$env:temp\BGInfo" -Force

# check for BGIs
if (!(test-path *.bgi)) {
    write-host "- ERROR: There needs to be at least one .bgi file for the Component to work."
    write-host "  Execution cannot continue. Exiting."
    exit 1
} else {
    if (test-path *.bgi -exclude default.bgi) {
        $varArgs=(ls *.bgi -Exclude default.bgi | Select-Object -First 1).Name
        $varArgs=`'$varArgs`'
    } else {
        $varArgs='default.bgi'
    }
}

Move-Item $varArgs "$env:temp\BGInfo" -Force

# furnish a quick CMD script
 set-content "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\BGILaunch.cmd" -value '@echo off'
 add-content "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\BGILaunch.cmd" -value "$env:temp\BGInfo\bginfo$([intptr]::Size).exe `"$env:temp\BGInfo\$varArgs`" /silent /nolicprompt /timer:0"
# add-content "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\BGILaunch.cmd" -value 'echo Please wait -- Configuring wallpaper'
# add-content "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\BGILaunch.cmd" -value "ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > nul"

# inform the user
# write-host "- BGInfo has been installed and configured to run on Startup."
# write-host "  Endpoints will need to be rebooted for changes to take effect."
```

Comment: Have you used the PowerShell ISE to step through each line of your script to determine the value of the variable on line 25 before it executes?

Comment: No, I didn't create this script or am familiar with it. I'm on the Desktop deployment side trying to figure out how to get it from stop erroring. I apologize for my difficulty in understanding.

Does it mean there's a problem with the format of the code `'$varArgs`' ?

Comment: You need to debug the script.  `(ls *.txt -Exclude "Test.txt" | Select-Object -First 1).Name` returns the first .txt file that isn't `Text.txt` so the problem isn't that line which means the issue is with the next line

Comment: Line 25 in my testing is not required.  The previous line already returns the name of the file.  The only arguments for Move-Item is the path to the file you want to move and the path to the foder where it will be moved to.

Comment: In the future you should use PowerShell ISE to get a better understanding of the script you are using.  In this case the syntax within your PowerShell script was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your script syntax is incorrect.

```
if (!(test-path *.bgi)) {
    write-host "- ERROR: There needs to be at least one .bgi file for the Component to work."
    write-host "  Execution cannot continue. Exiting."
    exit 1
} else {
    if (test-path *.bgi -exclude default.bgi) {
        $varArgs=(ls *.bgi -Exclude default.bgi | Select-Object -First 1).Name
        $varArgs=`'$varArgs`'
    } else {
        $varArgs='default.bgi'
    }
}
```

should be the following:

```
if (!(test-path *.bgi)) {
    write-host "- ERROR: There needs to be at least one .bgi file for the Component to work."
    write-host "  Execution cannot continue. Exiting."
    exit 1
} else {
    if (test-path *.bgi -exclude default.bgi) {
        $varArgs=(ls *.bgi -Exclude default.bgi | Select-Object -First 1).Name            
    } else {
        $varArgs='default.bgi'
    }
}
```

I was able to determine this behavior by running the following:

```
$varArgs=(ls *.txt -Exclude "Test.txt" | Select-Object -First 1).Name
Move-Item $varArgs "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\New folder"
```

It moved the first .txt file that wasn't "Test.txt" on my Desktop into a folder called New Folder that existed on my Desktop.

Comment: The intention of the line I remove was to make it so `(ls *.bgi -Exclude default.bgi | Select-Object -First 1).Name` was the argument sent to Move-Item.  Which could be done of course by simply enclosing that command in quotes.  Of course that is unnecessary in my testing. Worth pointing out my modifications find the file in the directory where the script is ran. Which looking at the original version was also the case.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, removing that line did correct the issue